# Manually entering a system date env var string in Linux - it works in Unix, but not in Linux

Tags: linux

entered on the UI:
system_date='2019-08-17 09:30:01'  -- this works in Unix HP/UX
 In Red Hat Linux when this env var is exported, only the date is recognized, the space and timestamp are not being recognized.  I tried double quotes but it did not recognize that either, it just went to the next env var on the screen.

I tried to enter a | instead of the space, and that worked, however the application dictates that a space be entered. How can I enter the system date/timestamp in Red Hat Linux so that it can be exported in its entirety without truncating everything after the date?

Comment: Where in the "UI" are you entering this? In a terminal window? If so what shell are you using? In a Bourne shell derivative you would say `system_date=`2019-08-17 09:30:01' ; echo "$system_date"`. If you are trying to actually set the date then the original format for doing so would be 081709302019.01, i.e. MMDDhhmmYYYY.ss

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually doing or what "not being recognised" means as you don't show any commands or error messages.

Comment: After the system exports the system_date (date + timestamp), any echo of the system_date will only include the date, without the timestamp.  Before export system date ='2019-08-18 09:09:03'  After the export: '2019-08-18'.... Thanks

Comment: It is being entered in an application, actually called Application Manager, i.e. Appworx.  It is entered as  system_date='2019-08-18 09:09:03' e.g.  After the export  of the env var, everything after the 2019-08-18 is being ignored. Thanks

Comment: `Appworx application manager` appears to be a commercial java program for scheduling jobs, currently owned by broadcom.